# Program a function that creates a new array containing only the empty values from the previous array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

This is the code used to create my initial array:

```
Dim StartBoard(1 To 3, 1 To 3)  As Variant
StartBoard(1, 1) = "A"
StartBoard(1, 2) = 1
StartBoard(1, 3) = "B"
StartBoard(2, 1) = "B"
StartBoard(2, 2) = 4
StartBoard(2, 3) = "A"
StartBoard(3, 1) = 6
StartBoard(3, 2) = "B"
StartBoard(3, 3) = "A"
```

I am trying to create a function that gives me an array of the same size, but removes all the A's and B's. This is what I have so far which produces a "Type Mismatch":

```
Function EmptyCells(Board) As Variant
Dim outputArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant
i = 1
j = 1
For i = 1 To 3
If Board(i, i) = "A" Or "B" Then
outputArray(i, i) = ""
Else
Board(i, i) = outputArray(i, i)
End If
Next
EmptyCells = outputArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `j` loop.  I also made it dynamic so Board can be any size.

Also the `If` should be `If Board(i, j) = "A" Or Board(i, j) ="B" Then`

```
Function EmptyCells(Board() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    ReDim outputArray(LBound(Board, 1) To UBound(Board, 1), LBound(Board, 2) To UBound(Board, 2)) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Board, 1) To UBound(Board, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(Board, 2) To UBound(Board, 2)
            If Board(i, j) = "A" Or Board(i, j) = "B" Then
                outputArray(i, j) = ""
            Else
                outputArray(i, j) = Board(i, j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    EmptyCells = outputArray
    
End Function
```